# is there any replacement for creating 100 labels and putting informations on it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle, datatable

I am having a `sql` like shown below which will retrieve around 100's of information's and push in to `datatable` .Here in this question i am showing a minimal `sql` and display the data.Next What i did is i took all these information's and assigned to the labels and displayed like shown below
[image]

Is there any better way i can display the data as shown.In these scenario if some body wants to display again 50 information's, again i have to create 50 labels and display those information's.If i transpose the data from data table and assign those information to a `gridview` where i set `autogenerate= true`,i will not get these look and feel.DO i have a better way to display these `readonly` informations.Is there any way i can design a `gridview` and show all these informations in to it

Comment: show your design how you doing now , my suggestion would be a `repeater` , anyways show your markup so that it would be help full to give a appropriate suggestion

Comment: @Webruster the design i posted already an image.But i used lables for everything ,for displaying like Additional Infomration as label text,for displaying TRUPDATE from database as assing values from database to a lable

Comment: i'm asking about the `HTML`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Repeater controls did the magic,thanks Webruster